# How to generate 1825 numbers with a step of 0.01 in a specific range

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In the following code I want to get len(a) should be 1825 keeping step 0.01. But when I print len(a) it gives me 73. For getting length of 1825 I have to generate numbers from 2.275 to 3 with a step of 0.01 ,73 times. How can I do that? I tried to use np.linspace but that command doesn't work for this case.

```
a = np.arange(2.275, 3, 0.01)
```

Comment: `0.01` is not `0.001` (and you should use `linspace` anyway).

Comment: Also, it'd be 725 numbers, not 1825.

Comment: No I want to keep step 0.01.

Comment: 1825 is the len(a). I want to generate numbers from 2.275 to 3 with a step of 0.01. And want to repeat it several times such that len(a) should be 1825

Comment: A step of 0.01 will never result in 1825 numbers unless you allow duplicates. Your step size must be approximately 0.000397 or less.

Comment: Are you looking for ordered repeated values or random values?

Comment: yes step of 0.01 can never give a length of 1825. But if we do 2.275,2.285, 2.295,..3. and repeat same process several times then we can get this number. I am getting confuse ow to do that

Comment: yes I am looking for orderd  repeated values

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to `np.random.choice` 1825 times

```
>>> a = np.arange(2.275,3,0.01)
>>> c = np.random.choice(a, 1825)

array([2.995, 2.545, 2.755, ..., 2.875, 2.275, 2.605])

>>> c.shape
(1825,)
```

---

Edit

If you want `a` repeated 25 times (i.e. 1825/73) in sequence, use [**`np.tile()`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html)

```
target = 1825
n = target/len(a)

np.tile(a, int(n))
```

yields

```
array([2.275, 2.285, 2.295, ..., 2.975, 2.985, 2.995])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner, given `a = np.arange(2.275, 3, 0.01)` and `n = 1825`:

```
a = np.broadcast_to(a, (n // a.size + book(n % a.size), a.size)).ravel()[:n]
```

This uses [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) to turn `a` into a matrix where it repeats itself enough times to fill 1825 elements. [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html) then flattens the repeated list and the final slice chops off the unwanted elements. The `ravel` operation is what actually copies the list since the broadcast uses stride tricks to avoid copying the data.